# Liferay 7.1 : include my theme war in my panel app

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I'm in Liferay 7.1.

I have a xxxTheme in the folder WARS. This theme is applied on public and private pages.

I've created an module panelApp, located in the user accordion in the side nav.

How could I apply my theme in the view of my panel app ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel apps located in the user accordion will use the control panel theme. The public and private pages as you mentioned are not related to that section of your system.

You will be able to use by changing your control panel theme to your theme. Although, you might need to change some pieces of your theme to support the control panel components with your style.